# How to mount a key holder with a sawtooth hanger on the back?

Tags: screws, mounting, nails

I have this small wooden decorative key hanger with two hooks on the front (back side pictured below):

[image: back of key hanger]

It has a sawtooth hanger on the back. I have been mounting it with a couple of nails (e.g. as suggested in [How to hang a frame with a sawtooth hanger from a wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/212733/how-to-hang-a-frame-with-a-sawtooth-hanger-from-a-wall)), but because it's a key holder it gets moved around a lot, with keys being added and removed frequently. So over time the nails get loose and the key hanger tilts or can fall down. I think it's just drywall in the spot where I'm mounting it, in a small section of wall between the front door and a corner.

Should I put in a couple of anchored screws instead? How can I best ensure it stays put? Because if I just put two screws side by side it could still move around. I was considering adding another screw or nail in the top corner of the opening on the side to help reduce rotation, which probably would not be too noticeable.

Alternatively, should I remove the sawtooth hanger and replace it with something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use some poster putty or removable double-sided foam tape also.

Either pop a nail in a fresh spot or use a small screw in a plug anchor, then add several balls of poster putty or pads of foam tape to the back of the panel. Level it and press it firmly in place. The anchor will provide initial support, but the poster putty will lock it in place well enough that it won't work loose again.

You could also just use 3M Command<sup>™</sup> mounts. They're pretty amazing. Take the hanger off first.

Comment: I agree with the idea of Command mounts. I use them and they work well and are removable, as long as you leave the tab exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Find a stud. Put a long screw in the drywall and stud. Leave the head out a little bit to hold the sawtooth.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a pretty narrow stretch of wall between the right side of the front door and the corner, like 1 foot wide. There is no stud in the middle. But maybe that just means I should find another wall for the key hanger, if a stud is the only way to go… Would presumably also need at least two screws to help keep it level, no?

Comment: Even if you get a solid screw in the wall this thing will flop around with use. You want it secure and immovable.

Comment: Yes two is better.

Answer (score 0):

If it tips due to the weight of keys on one side but not the other, you could use two screws/nails next to each other. Getting two screws close enough to each other that you can get them into this one hanger would be a bit dicey when going into drywall, I'd stick with nails.

The other option would be to add another sawtooth hanger to it and put a single nail for each. You could put the other hanger where the "1400" label is - there's no need for them to be on the same level. Two points of contact will keep it from tipping when there are only keys on one side.

Comment: yea there are two nails now

Comment: I think if I add a hanger where the 1400 label is, the key hanger will still tip to the left if keys are hung on the left hook. Also the nails in the drywall will come loose over time, as is already the case.

Comment: Key racks get bumped. Doesn't matter how many screws if the only thing holding it in position is its own weight.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, if you want it to be relatively permanent, you could simply *glue* it to the wall.

Comment: What kind of glue would be strong enough?

Comment: I would say pretty much any kind of construction adhesive would be.  Maybe something like Loctite Power Grab?